# Stack Overflow in Recursion for big value of n

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, biginteger, bitwise-xor

**How Can I Fix this Stack Overflow for Big value of n? It is working fine for small integers.**
I have been attached the question link for reference.
https://codeforces.com/contest/1208/problem/A
Can we do it by iterative method?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class XORinacci {

  public static int Rinacci(int a, int b, int n) {
    if (n == 0) return a; else if (n == 1) return b;

    return Rinacci(a, b, n - 1) ^ Rinacci(a, b, n - 2);
  }

  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = scan.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[T];
    int a, b, n;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
      a = scan.nextInt();
      b = scan.nextInt();
      n = scan.nextInt();
      arr[i] = Rinacci(a, b, n);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
    scan.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: try increasing the jvm stack size with `-Xss` command line option. This will raise the upper bound for SOE.

Comment: I would say, the major problem here is the recursion. Java stores every method call on its stack. Once the stack gets larger than the maximum stack size, you'll get a Stackoverflow.
Try to compute the numbers the other way around. Compute XORinaci of 0 and 1 first and compute the following numbers using a while-loop until you reach the required number.